# Angular bootstraping doesn't work after browser refresh

Tags: angularjs

I have strange problem with angular bootstraping.

I can't paste whole code but shortly:

- there's no ng-app in index.html
- there's jQuery ajax to check if I'm signed in
- if I'm signed in - I call (and it's OK):

  ```
  angular.element('body').ready(function(){
    angular.bootstrap(angular.element('body'),['app']);
    console.log('is always called'); //is always called
  })
  ```
- if I'm not signed in I do:

  ```
  app = angular.injector(['app.templates'])
  content = app.get('$templateCache').get('login.html')

  $compile = app.get('$compile')
  $scope = app.get('$rootScope').$new(true)
  $('body').append content
  $compile($('body').contents())($scope)
  $scope.login = function() { // doing login ajax }
  ```

  and it works fine as well.
- in $scope.login function I'm doing ajax which is bootstrapping angular app (code at the top) and it's is OK
- in my angular app I have signout function which is doing simple jQuery ajax call to signout on server side
- after successful signout I'm doing `window.location.reload(true/false doesn't matter)` and after reload I see login form, I do login, angular app starts and is is OK
- I'm logged in, I have angular app, I do browser refresh (F5) - and it's OK (signup check, bootstrap)

The point is:

While I'm signed out and I do page refresh (F5) page reloads, signup form is visible but after successful signup ajax angular isn't bootstrapping?

Another page refresh is doing signup check and is bootstrapping ok, signout is doing `window.location.reload()` (which should be equivalent to F5) and successful signup IS bootstrapping.

Another thing - after successful signup I changed from angular bootstrap to window.location.reload(true/false doesn't matter), page reloads and should do signup check which should result in bootstrapping angular app but it DOES NOT. I have to refresh page again and it STARTS o_O

I have absolutely no idea what to do.

Comment: why are you trying to initialize all the components manually instead of using `angular.bootstrap()` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)?  trying to manually create your own `$rootscope` and manually `$compile` is a recipe for disaster.